# How to load/show more than 100 cells(rows) in uitableview or retrieve latest messages in uitableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am making chat application in which want to retrieve latest messages in table cells/rows.If messages are less than 100 then i can able to retrieve latest messages in table view but when message count are more than 100 then it can not retrieve latest messages.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [chatData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
chatCell *cell = (chatCell *)[tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CHAT_CELL_IDENTIFIER];
NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
if (row < chatData.count)
{
    NSString *chatText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:TEXT];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    CGSize size = [chatText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(225.0f, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];
    cell.textString.frame = CGRectMake(75, 14, size.width +20, size.height + 20); // set text frame
    cell.textString.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE];        // set text font
    cell.textString.text = chatText;                                              // set text
    [cell.textString sizeToFit];
    NSDate *theDate = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:DATE];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:DATE_FORMAT];
    NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
    cell.timeLabel.text = timeString;                                       // set timeLabel to display date and time
    cell.userLabel.text = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:NAME]; // set userLabel to display userName
}
return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:TEXT];
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(225.0f, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
return labelSize.height + 40;
}




- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];

if (tfEntry.text.length>0)
{
    // updating the table immediately
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:TEXT,SET_SENDER ,SET_RECEIVER ,DATE ,nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tfEntry.text, Sender, receiver, [NSDate date], nil];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
    [chatData addObject:dictionary];

    NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [insertIndexPaths addObject:newPath];
    [chatTable beginUpdates];
    [chatTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [chatTable endUpdates];
    [chatTable reloadData];

    // going for the parsing
    PFObject *newMessage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:CHATROOM];
    [newMessage setObject:tfEntry.text forKey:TEXT];
    [newMessage setObject:self.userId forKey:SET_SENDER];
    [newMessage setObject:receiver forKey:SET_RECEIVER];
    [newMessage setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:DATE];
    [newMessage setObject:self.user.userName forKey:NAME];
    [newMessage saveInBackground];
    localChatCount = [chatData count];
    newChatMessage = NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE;
    tfEntry.text = @"";
}
return NO;
}
```

So what is the procedure to retrieve latest messages in tableview if row/cell count is more than 100? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show some source code?

Comment: yeah.I added source code.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I did not really understand what happens with those cells > 100? Can't you create them? Don't they show up? Can't you scroll further down? What makes you belive that 100 is the threshold where the problem comes up?

Comment: when rows reaching more than 100 then it is not retrieving from database.So rows which are more than 100, they dont show up.May be it is not retrieving from array or table view.

Comment: how many objects are in chatData? Where do you fill chatData with data? What is it and how is chatData declared?

Comment: Can you add the definition and properties of `chatData`?

Comment: chatdata is nsmutablearray.

Comment: I find solution by setting limit and skip value for PFQuery object(Parse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted rows if table rows are more than 100 and retrieving latest 100 rows from parse table. So there is no need of more than 100 rows.

I also can set limit and skip value for PFQuery object if table rows are more than 100.